# Is it right to use the verb Make in "Pig kidneys make the best breakfast (s) ever"?

Tags: verbs

I was watching some video on youtube and a person in it said:

> Pig kidneys **make** the best breakfast **(s)** ever.

Now, I what I couldn't help thinking about whether how he used the verb **make** where he did was grammatically correct. 
Is it? 
And one more thing I want to know is whether to use **breakfast** here, or **breakfasts**.

Comment: Could you post the link to the video as well?

Comment: James Joyce might agree - “Mr Leopold Bloom ate with relish the inner organs of beasts and fowls" However, Bloom preferred mutton kidneys.

Comment: I can't actually, @CookieMonster.
A friend had me watch it on his ipad.

Comment: @CookieMonster 
Pig kidneys make the best breakfast ever. 
Does the above sentence seem grammatically correct to you?

Comment: @lekonchekon  I'm not sure I would trust anyone who likes pig kidneys for breakfast, or really any time.  But the grammar is fine, and either breakfast or breakfasts is fine.

Comment: Can you remember what the video was about? Was it a cooking tutorial for instance? Was it an interview/chat show? Was it a clip from a movie?  Was the person speaking well-known? American? British? Call your friend and ask him/her for the link. I *need* to know who this person is! ☻ Pig kidneys for breakfast? Yuk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compare:

> German Shepherds make the best police attack dogs. Bloodhounds make
>   the best trackers.  Golden Retrievers make good pets.

There, "make" means "to be suited to a particular role".

Pig kidneys are well suited to breakfast. They do well in that particular role in the cuisine.

The plural there (breakfasts) would suggest that the contents of the breakfast might vary, or the preparation. But it could also be the plural as a form of generalization, as in the canine examples (attack dogs, trackers, pets).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is grammatically correct. Make is a verb, "Pig kidneys" is a noun phrase, acting as the subject. "the best breakfast ever" is the object.

The sense is clear and idiomatic. Sense 4 of https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make#Verb gives the meaning "constitute" with the example "They make a cute couple."

Breakfast is preferred over "breakfasts"

Comment: "Breakfast is preferred over 'breakfasts'" - can you provide some reasoning for this statement?

Comment: 'Pig kidneys' is the subject, so wouldn't that make this incorrect? Kidneys cannot 'do' anything. I would say "Pig kidneys make *for* the best breakfast (s) ever." instead. This doesn't insinuate an action.

Comment: @poepje See the other answer. "Make" doesn't mean to do anything here, it means to be suited to.